# Spring Security default password is not printing on console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have added spring security dependency in my pom.xml file but not able to see my default password on console. I have added the following dependency

```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

My main class looks like

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.gonkar.fleetms.models"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.gonkar.fleetms.repositories"})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.gonkar.fleetms"})
public class FleetManagementSytemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FleetManagementSytemApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I tried with adding the following properties in my properties file but no luck
`logging.level.org.springframework.security=INFO`

A password is not printing on console I tried with adding

```
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=pwd
```

but no luck, it's not reading above properties from the properties file.

---

Note :
I don't know why but when I removed componentScan annotation from main class , It starts printing default password at console. As per my observation when I use componentScan annotation its not printing default password at console

---

Comment: @Alien Thanks for your quick reply , 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security' When I added this property its showing warning like 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security' is an unknown property.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below property and see if that works.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security=INFO
```

Or

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security =INFO
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply , 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security' When I added this property its showing warning like 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security' is an unknown property

Comment: What about the first one.?  logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security=INFO

Comment: Can you try @EnableWebSecurity on main class.

Comment: Yes I tried it already ,  but not working in my case. Also Why its not reading from properties file.

Comment: I don't know why but when I removed componentScan annotation from main class ,  It starts printing default password at console

Answer (score 0):

disable the settings in application.properties or application.yml

```
#logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using InMemoryUserDetailsManager to make a configuration class the spring security will not display any password. You need to to use the credentials of the user you created using UserDetails

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

By default, the Spring Security starter does not expose user passwords; it follows secure practices such as password hashing. However, in certain cases, you may need to adjust logging properties to modify the default behavior. In my case, I encountered a similar issue and attempted to address it by adding the following properties:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security =INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

Despite these adjustments, I observed that the passwords continued to be displayed in the logs even after commenting out the configurations. I am seeking an explanation for this behavior and would appreciate any insights or solutions from others who may have encountered a similar issue.

Comment: he is not referring to user passwords he is referring to the default password that is written in the console when you add spring security as a dependency to a project as mentioned here in the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/getting-started.html#servlet-hello-starting